# Angular 5 Access-Control-Allow-Origin error with localhost

Tags: cors, localhost, angular-http

I'm leaning Angular, trying to use HTTP get to a file on my PC. I want to simulate the server scenario so tried serving the file with the following,  (live-server, browser-sync & xampp) one at a time, but with every try I get the error

> Failed to load http://localhost/ng-data/products.json: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'http://localhost:4200/' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access

When I paste the url (http://localhost/ng-data/products.json) in my browser I can get the file.

Comment: you need to add the port `:4200` to the http call

Comment: Why the down vote?? if my file is inside htdocs in xampp files, why wouldi add port 4200?

Comment: Angular is serving from 4200, but the file is somewhere else not in angular projects

Comment: i presume youre using `ng serve` to run the webpage? how are you serving the data?

Comment: Yes ng serve for angular,

Comment: the data is served from xampp so localhost/<path to data/ json file>

Comment: in which case, it sounds like you need to enable cors on the server/xampp

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Because you're testing, I suggest you use the Chrome extension. Please search this in the Chrome extension list as shown below and then enable it. Probably your problem will be solved.

[image]

Comment: I'll try that,, by the way i didnt downvote your answer

Comment: how would this affect an angular webpage?

Answer (score 2):

I found other 2 ways to work around this situation,

## solution 1:

To change the products.json file to products.php, then add this at the top:

```
<?php  
  'header(Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *)';
  'header(Content-Type: application/json)'
?>
```

finally, change the url which you are connecting to, from products.json to products.php

## solution 2

using proxy configuration see: [Angular documentatiom](https://juristr.com/blog/2016/11/configure-proxy-api-angular-cli/)

follow these steps:

1- change the url inside the service to '/api/products' instead of 'http://localhost/products'

2- create proxy.config.json file in the root directory of your angular project
add this code inside it:

```
    {
  "/api/*": {
    "target": "http://localhost",
    "secure": false,
    "logLevel": "debug",
    "changeOrigin": true
  }
}
```

3- create folder api on the server and add the products.json inside it.

Note: in my case i'm using localhost with no port specified as i'm using xampp. but if ur using node for example you will specify the port like: localhost:3000 in proxy.config.json